# How to check a post exist when the permalink has post id in it?

Tags: posts, permalinks

This is my permalink structure

```
/%post_id%-%postname%/
```

https://example.com/in/140521-test-post/

https://example.com/us/140524-second-post/

How can I check "test-post" exist or not? I'm using wpml for multi language so not able to check using slug.

Post ID is causing issues while checking. Is there any solution for this?

When using url_to_postid(), this format is working
https://example.com/in/test-post/, but not this

https://example.com/in/140521-test-post/

For example:

```
url_to_postid('https://example.com/in/test-post/');
```

any solution to handle with post id?

```
url_to_postid('https://example.com/in/[%post_id%-]test-post/');
url_to_postid('https://example.com/in/[\d\-]+test-post/');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of issues? How do you check it currently?

Comment: Currently I'm checking using url_to_postid function
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/url_to_postid/

Comment: NB: I'm using WPML plugin for multilanguage